# iOS: How to update the sqlite correctly in background when a response from the server is received (in multi thread)?

Tags: ios, sqlite, grand-central-dispatch

I would like to update of my sqlite when I get an answer from the server.

I use that code to launch several thread in background:

```
  if ([[Reachability sharedManager] isInternetOk])
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ //FIXME: SENDING MAILS
            [self getMailsToShareImagesWithHTML:modalView.HTMLPath];
        });
    }
```

And in my getMailsToShareImages, I check all the mails to send in my sqlite:

```
NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *dbPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mails.db", user_appli]];

    // Open the database. The database was prepared outside the application.
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Open Database OK");

        //1st query
        NSString *queryOrders = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ID, MAIL, MEDIAPATH, SEND "
                                "FROM MAILS "
                                "WHERE SEND = '0' "
                                "AND TYPE = 'IMAGE' "
                                "LIMIT 10 "];

        const char *sqlStatement = [queryOrders cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSNumber *ID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0)];
                NSString *MAIL = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,1)];
                NSString *MEDIAPATH = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,2)];
                NSString *SEND = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,3)];
                NSLog(@"ID : %@", ID);
                NSLog(@"MAIL : %@", MAIL);
                NSLog(@"MEDIAPATH : %@", MEDIAPATH);
                NSLog(@"SEND : %@", SEND);

                [self shareImageToMail:MAIL withId:ID withMediaPath:MEDIAPATH WithHTML: HTMLPath];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"SQL statement KO");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    //sqlite3_close(database); // I commented that line to attempt to avoid problems without success.
}
```

My problem is that it doesn't update my database when it launches 40 thread for example, I think it attempt to access a lot at the database may be ?

I update my database like this:

```
- (void) shareImageToMail:(NSString *)MAIL withId:(NSNumber *)ID withMediaPath:(NSString *)MEDIAPATH WithHTML:(NSString *) HTMLPath
{
  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
#if DEBUG
            NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"requestReply: %@, error: %@", requestReply, error);
#endif
            if (error == nil)
            {
                [[DataManagement sharedManager] mailsSentWithId:ID];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Could not send mail!!!");
            }
        }] resume];
    }
...
```

Update function:

```
- (NSString *)updateSQL:(NSString*) querySQL
    {
        NSString *result = @"UPDATE_KO";

        NSLog(@"SQL : %@", querySQL);
        if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Open Database OK");

            const char *sqlStatement = [querySQL cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Update database KO");
                    NSLog(@"SQL : %@", querySQL);
                    result = @"UPDATE_NO";
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Update database OK");
                    result = @"UPDATE_ON";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"SQL UPDATE statement KO");
                NSLog(@"SQL : %@", querySQL);
                result = @"UPDATE_KO";
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Open Database KO");
            result = @"UPDATE_KO";
        }
//        sqlite3_close(database);
//        NSLog(@"Close Database OK");

        return result;
    }
```

How can I launch all my update & insert processes in my database correctly and/or sequentially?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and where is your updating code? you show us SELECT and you talk about updating database

Comment: @Lu_ Ooops, you're right, I juste updated my answer.

Comment: you are preparing statement and then not doing anything with it

Comment: @Lu_ In the querySQL there is the update string for info

Comment: i can't see it, what are logs? you say that nothing updates but did you try just some test data? what is the error?